# I want to use optimise my recursive solution using memoisation for Distinct Subsequences problem

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

the problem statement is:
Given two sequences A and B, count number of unique ways in sequence A, to form a subsequence that is identical to the sequence B.
Subsequence : A subsequence of a string is a new string which is formed from the original string by deleting some (can be none) of the characters without disturbing the relative positions of the remaining characters. (ie, "ACE" is a subsequence of "ABCDE" while "AEC" is not).

Goal:
I want to optimise my recursive solution using dp

My Approach:
I am trying to make every possible subsequence of given string and if subsequence matches with pattern ans will be ans=ans+1.

I want to memoize the solution and use dp to optimise time complexity but cannot think how to do that.

code:

```
int funct(string &given,string &target,string &curr, int index)
{
    if(curr == target)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if( index >= given.size() )
    return 0;
    int without = funct(given,target,curr,index+1);
    curr.push_back(given[index]);
    int with = funct(given,target,curr,index+1);
    curr.pop_back();
    return with+without;
}
int Solution::numDistinct(string A, string B) 
{
    string s;
    return funct(A,B,s,0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Let A has the length L1 and B has the length L2.
- Let f(i,j) be a function that gives you the number of ways you can get the sequence B(j...L2-1) from the sequence A(i...L1-1), then the answer to your problem will be f(0,0).
- Please take note that the sequence A(i...L1-1) means the substring A(i...L1-1) and B(j...L2-1) means the substring B(j...L2-1).

Here is the code written in C++:

```
int memo[100][100];
string A, B;

int f(int i, int j) {
    if (i >= A.length() || j >= B.length()) return 0;
    if (A[i] == B[j]) {
        if (j == B.length() - 1)
            memo[i][j] = 1 + f(i + 1 , j);
        else
            memo[i][j] = f(i + 1, j + 1) + f(i + 1, j);
    }
    else {
        memo[i][j] = f(i + 1, j);
    }
    return memo[i][j];
}
```